# Expo ejection & channel change clears AsyncStorage

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I recently ejected from Expo, SDK 36, into ExpoKit. I then built the application using a different channel than the previous build.

I uploaded it to TestFlight and downloaded it, but this completely cleared AsyncStorage.

Is this a problem with TestFlight/iOS clearing the data, or is it the ejection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem after Eject using SDK37.
In my case, the problem was that the path of AsyncStorage had changed and I had to migrate It was.

Ref: "https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2805"